# Querying all contacts from DE field in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql

Is there a way to query all contacts based on a data extension field? IE query everyone with the last name "Johnson" and the DE field is Last Name. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a basic use of the [WHERE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) clause. Here's an example:

```
SELECT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name
WHERE condition;
```

In your example, it could be something like this:

```
SELECT [Last Name] FROM <<insert the name of your Data Extension>>
WHERE [Last Name] = 'Johnson'
```

If you have a space in the column name, make sure to put it in [].

There are many online platforms where you can learn SQL for free, for example, [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_intro.asp).
If you're not sure which "version" of SQL to learn, Marketing Cloud is using SQL Server 2005 capabilities.